# Reject Angularjs resource promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

So I'm working on a Angularjs based mobile app. When a user taps on each of the tabs along the bottom a new route is called which is loading the partial and controller.

In my controllers I often then request data from the server via Angularjs $resource such as

```
$rootScope.getPage = pageApi.query();    // GET
$rootScope.getPage = $rootScope.getPage.$promise.then(function(data) {

  //Do stuff with the returned data

});
```

I'm using root scope here because I have a spinning loader located outside of the controllers own $scope. While waiting for the response I'm using an Angular directive ([Angular Busy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy)) to display a loader.

However as the user moves through the pages on the app, more and more promises are started (that, for example, might not be resolved as the connection has been lost).

**How can I resolve / reject any other promises so that only the most recently loaded controller is waiting on a promise ?**

All comments / answers are really appreciated!

Thanks,
Mac

Comment: Why not use current controller's $scope and just update a variable on the $rootScope inside the `then` callback.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/domenic/last

Comment: I'm having the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440177/angularjs-how-to-cancel-resource-promise-when-switching-routes) and can't find a solution anywhere. You'd think this was a common problem. Have you found an answer?

Comment: @mac Did you get solution for this issue ?

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Hey! I believe in Angular JS 1.5 $resource supports a cancellable:true option on 'actions'. You can then call $cancelRequest() on it. With Angular versions below that you can use the timeout option on $http